# Javascript regex expression to match numbers group in ABC13 80 55 5600 6000 2700 SDR3 Comment

Tags: javascript, regex

I need some help with writing a regex to match only numbers/number groups in a string:

`8000 30 4000` should match `8000 30 4000`

`ABC13 8000 3999 2999 Comment` should match `[space]8000 3999 2999[space]`

`ABC13 80 55 5600 6000 2700 SDR3 Comment` should match `[space]80 55 5600 6000 2700[space]`

I have tried this so far:

```
([^a-zA-Z]+[^0-9]{0,2})+(\s*\d{0,4}\s*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overthinking this a bit. And you have also got some [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) in there. All you need spaces, digits and a wordboundary:

```
\s*\b[\d\s]+\b\s*
```

This will work work for all three cases. The `\s*` capture any optional spaces along the way, while word boundary `\b` makes sure, that the second and third case do not include the `13` in the match.

If you want to make sure that every number has at most 4 digits:

```
\s*\b(?:\d{1,4}\s+)*\d{1,4}\b\s*
```